# How to use path (address[]) correctly when interacting with Uniswap using Etherscan

Tags: etherscan, uniswap

I'm trying to use Uniswap V2: Router 2 through Etherscan:

```
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630b4cf539739df2c5dacb4c659f2488d#writeContract
```

As a test example I am looking to swap 10 RFI (contract address: `0xa1afffe3f4d611d252010e3eaf6f4d77088b0cd7`) for YLD (contract address: `0xdcb01cc464238396e213a6fdd933e36796eaff9f`).

I put the amountOutMin number very low so it would go through no matter what. Sadly I don't think I've input the swap route correctly? Any advice would be appreciated.

Writing contract swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens

```
amountIn (uint256)
10000000000000000000

amountOutMin (uint256)
500000000000000

path (address[])
["0xa1afffe3f4d611d252010e3eaf6f4d77088b0cd7", "0xdcb01cc464238396e213a6fdd933e36796eaff9f"]

to (address)
0x[redacted]

deadline (uint256)
1611748800

Error thrown: invalid address (arg="path", coderType="
```

[image: image of the error the contract throws]

Comment: sorry for the noob problems... will look to do this on something like brownie via Vyper once I feel a bit more competent.

Comment: resolved, address format was: 0xa1afffe3f4d611d252010e3eaf6f4d77088b0cd7,0xdcb01cc464238396e213a6fdd933e36796eaff9f

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that there's a pool available containing those two tokens?
One reason for failure is that a pool doesn't exist for the pair.
Another might be that there isn't enough liquidity.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65966)